How select query from record count more than 1 and count more than 2 with custom column (Option) in MS Access
I'm trying to select query from record count more than 1 (ID&DATE&INOUT) and count more than 2 (ID&DATE) with custom column (Option) in MS Access
so with "NO" in the option column then the record more than 1 and more than 2 is not included in my sql query code
example for ID 5045 Date 12-Jul-24 should only appear 3 records because they have been marked in the option column NO
Is there something wrong with my SQL code ?
Please Guide me
Table Absen for testing



ID
DATE
TIME
INOUT
OPTION




5045
12-Jul-24
08:11:36
IN



5045
12-Jul-24
08:11:38
IN



5045
12-Jul-24
17:01:01
IN



5045
12-Jul-24
0
OUT
NO


5045
21-Jun-24
08:16:10
IN



5045
21-Jun-24
17:04:45
OUT



5045
22-Jun-24
08:18:14
IN



5045
21-May-24
08:19:25
IN



5045
21-May-24
17:04:40
OUT
NO


5009
29-Apr-24
17:00:00
OUT
NO


5009
29-Apr-24
08:00:00
IN



5009
29-Apr-24
17:00:00
OUT



5011
30-Apr-24
08:00:00
IN



5011
30-Apr-24
08:00:00
IN



5011
30-Apr-24
17:00:00
OUT



5045
11-Sep-24
08:18:14
IN



5045
11-Sep-24
08:19:25
IN




Table MASTERID



ID
NAMEID
POSITIONID




5045
E
STAFF


5009
B
STAFF


5011
D
STAFF



with Code Answer update
SELECT a.ID, MASTERID.NAMEID, a.DATE, a.TIME, a.INOUT
FROM ABSEN AS a INNER JOIN MASTERID ON a.ID = MASTERID.ID
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM ABSEN AS a2
       WHERE a.ID = a2.ID 
         and a.DATE = a2.DATE and a.INOUT = a2.INOUT
         and IIF(a2.OPTION IS NULL, '', a2.OPTION) <> 'NO'
       ) > 1 OR  (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM ABSEN AS a2
       WHERE a.ID = a2.ID 
         and a.DATE = a2.DATE
         and IIF(a2.OPTION IS NULL, '', a2.OPTION) <> 'NO'
       ) > 2 
ORDER BY a.ID, a.DATE, a.INOUT;


Result From code



ID
NAMEID
DATE
TIME
INOUT




5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
17:00:00
OUT


5045
E
12-Jul-24
17:01:01
IN


5045
E
12-Jul-24
08:11:38
IN


5045
E
12-Jul-24
08:11:36
IN


5045
E
12-Jul-24
00:00:00
OUT


5045
E
11-Sep-24
08:19:25
IN


5045
E
11-Sep-24
08:18:14
IN



Desired Result



ID
NAMEID
DATE
TIME
INOUT




5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
17:00:00
OUT


5045
E
12-Jul-24
17:01:01
IN


5045
E
12-Jul-24
08:11:38
IN


5045
E
12-Jul-24
08:11:36
IN


5045
E
11-Sep-24
08:19:25
IN


5045
E
11-Sep-24
08:18:14
IN




MASTERID doesn't have 5011? How can it be in the results?

The row you don't want in the output: (5045/12-Jul-2024/OUT) satisfies your rule: count more than 2 (ID&DATE) why shouldn't it be included?

@tinazmu  , MASTERID doesn't have 5011? How can it be in the results?  sorry for the typo I've updated in the post

@tinazmu , The row you don't want in the output: (5045/12-Jul-2024/OUT) satisfies your rule: count more than 2 (ID&DATE) why shouldn't it be included? because the row it is in the option column No

But your second condition doesn't look at INOUT so those rows with 5045/12-Jul-2024 with OPTION<>'N' are counted, and there are 3 so the row 5045/12-Jul-2024/OUT satisfies that criteria. If you want to exclude any rows with OPTION='N' then add another condition to the final WHERE

@tinazmu , FROM ABSEN AS a2 WHERE a.ID = a2.ID and a.DATE = a2.DATE and IIF(a2.OPTION IS NULL, '', a2.OPTION) <> 'NO') > 2 If I make only this condition  for testing 5009 29-Apr-24 OUT with option no it doesn't count but for 5011 12-Jul-2024 OUT with option no it count. add another condition to the final WHERE Please Guide me

You can exclude those directly, not based in count:
SELECT a.ID, MASTERID.NAMEID, a.DATE, a.TIME, a.INOUT
FROM ABSEN AS a INNER JOIN MASTERID ON a.ID = MASTERID.ID
WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM ABSEN AS a2
       WHERE a.ID = a2.ID 
         and a.DATE = a2.DATE and a.INOUT = a2.INOUT
         and IIF(a2.OPTION IS NULL, '', a2.OPTION) <> 'NO'
       ) > 1 OR  (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM ABSEN AS a2
       WHERE a.ID = a2.ID 
         and a.DATE = a2.DATE
         and IIF(a2.OPTION IS NULL, '', a2.OPTION) <> 'NO'
       ) > 2 )
AND IIF(a.OPTION IS NULL, '', a.OPTION) <> 'NO'


,Your answer is perfect and provides a solution for me

Hello sir, I have a new posting link , Maybe you can help me?
